# Auto redirect from https to http for a given url match .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, redirect

Here's my rewrite rule for .htaccess and I am pretty much new to this. I followed some examples but its not working in my case.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Force HTTP for /feed
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/feed
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# ensure https for all other except /feed
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feed [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

So all I need is whenever the url is `https://example.com/feed/somerandomtext` then it should be auto redirected to `http://example.com/feed/somerandomtext` and for other cases it should be served via https://

Any guidance in the right direction is much appreciated

Comment: Check if your rules get applied _at all_. Place a definite syntax error in that file, monitor your http servers error log file and make a request. Do you _really_ get an error?

Comment: I found that with some distributions of the apache web server `%{HTTPS}` is _not_ always said as claimed in the documentation. Have a try using `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443` instead.